# Error in opening of file. Python

Tags: python

I trying to open file and met some problem:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Here is the code example:

```
a = open(fname, "rb").read(255)
```

Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: What is fname? Can you show some more code. The one preceeding this

Comment: My guess is that fname is `None`

Comment: You think that fname contains a string but in fact, the way you have structured your previous code, fname is somehow being assigned `None`. That is why we are asking to see some more code.

Comment: Yes, I'm checked it. Actually, fname really contain the None

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fname` is `None`, not a string:

```
>>> open(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

You'll have to fix how you set `fname` or explicitly guard against it being `None`.